# If $x$ and $y$ are two linearly independent column $n$-vectors find all the eigenvalues of $xx^{T}-yy^{T}$

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, independence, transpose

If $x$ and $y$ are two linearly independent column $n$-vectors where $n\geq2$ .find all the eigenvalues of $xx^{T}-yy^{T}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: The matrix $xx^T-yy^T$ has rank $2$. So $n-2$ of the eigenvalues are $0$.

The other two eigenvectors have to lie in the columnspace of $xx^T-yy^T$, which is $\text{span}\{x,y\}$. So suppose $z = \alpha x + \beta y$ is an eigenvector of $xx^T-yy^T$ for some constants $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Can you find $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $(xx^T-yy^T)z = \lambda z$?